# 31 days in February in Date object

Tags: javascript, date

This code should log all days for given month:

```
var date = new Date(2012,2,1);
var thisMonth = date.getMonth();
while(date.getMonth()==thisMonth) { // 31 steps ???
    console.log(date.getMonth(),date.getDate());
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
}
```

It works well for every month but February. Any ideas where is the catch?

Comment: What index you use for February ....?? 1 or 2 ...??

Comment: Months are indexed from 0. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/HSECS/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the month parameter is **0-indexed**, so your code is about **March** not **February**.

***[The doc:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)***

> **month**
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with **0 for January to
>   11 for December.**

Comment: Oh dear, seems like I became senile... sorry everybody for such a trivial question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `new Date(2012,1,1);` month is zero-based ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty interesting:

```
new Date('2014-02-28'); // Fri Feb 28 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date('2014-02-29'); // Sat Mar 01 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date('2014-02-30'); // Sun Mar 02 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date('2014-02-31'); // Mon Mar 03 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100
new Date('2014-02-32'); // Invalid Date
```